# Javascript function to load different config.json files depending on URL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have a mobile website that loads a config.json file using the following javascipt:

```
$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/config.json',
        contentType: 'plain/text; charset=UTF-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){

            initConfig($.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText));
        }
    });
```

I would like to be able to load a different config.json file depending on the environment.  For example, qa.site.com, staging.site.com, and www.site.com.  Currently the javascript only loads one file and its contents can only be either qa.site.com, staging.site.com or www.site.com.  How do I modify this existing code to work with all three environments?

Comment: Because the URL you provide is relative (omits the domain) your request will always pull the file from the same domain as the page you are running on.  If you want to issue cross-domain requests, that's a whole 'nother can of worms.

Comment: @MikeEdwards - any idea on how to approach them worms?..

Comment: Can you be more specific about your situation?  There are multiple approaches to XSS depending on your use case.  What site(s) are you loading pages from?  What condition are you checking to pick a config.json?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getConfigFile() {
    switch (window.location.host.split(':')[0]) {
        case 'qa.site.com':
            return 'config-1.json';
        case 'www.site.com':
        case 'site.com': // optional, remove if incorrect
            return 'config-2.json';
        default:
            return 'config-default.json';
    }
}

$.ajax({
   // ...
   url: getConfigFile(),
   // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it enough, I found the answer:

```
// Check URL address and set appropriate config.json file 
    var whichjson = (window.location.host);
    var configurl = '';

    function getConfigFile(configurl) {
    switch (whichjson) {
        case 'qa.site.com':
            var configurl = '/config-qa.json';
            return configurl;
            break;
        case 'staging.site.com':
            var configurl = '/config-stg.json';
            return configurl;
            break;
        default:
            var configurl = '/config-default.json';
            return configurl;
            break;
         }
    }

    // _request('/config.json', 'getLocalData', 'POST', '/', initConfig, false);
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: getConfigFile(),
        contentType: 'plain/text; charset=UTF-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            initConfig($.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText));
        }

    }
    );
```